# Flutter both directions of platform channel call?

Tags: flutter, flutter-platform-channel

According to current [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) of flutter platfrom channel it seems only possible to call host (Native) from client (Dart) and then we get response from host. Is there any possiblity of its reverse, e.g. to call directly Client from host?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using [`MethodChannel`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel-class.html).

You will to specify a call handler on your method channel by using [`setMethodCallHandler`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel/setMethodCallHandler.html).

As an example, the [Java version of `MethodChannel`](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/MethodChannel.html) has the [`invokeMethod`](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/MethodChannel.html#invokeMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) method just like the Dart class has. This means that you can use `invokeMethod` on all platform. If you are calling it from native, you will have to set a method call handler in Flutter and vise versa.
On **iOS** it is exactly the same.